# how to apply PropType in react-native functional component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint

I am trying to validate props with PropType but my eslist compiler showing me an error, see image

please correct me whats wrong with this?

[image]

Comment: can you try `SubHeader.propTypes={}` and see

Comment: lol sorry its silly mistake anyways thank you for support @AravindS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with the code is that you are using `PropTypes` instead of `propTypes`.
Notice the lower case 'p'

```
SubHeader.propTypes = {
    left: PropTypes.array,
    center: PropTypes.array,
    right: PropTypes.array,
 }
```

There is no difference with stateful components when validating props

Here is the link you want to read more on [validating props](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, problem us casing of letter. Its lowercase `p`.

```
SubHeader.propTypes = {
     left: PropTypes.array,
     center: PropTypes.array,
     right: PropTypes.array,   
 }
```

Keep this thing in mind always, how we are importing:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

and a github issue [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1420) and propType docs [here](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types)